# Autocomplete based on all the files in a project in Atom

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

Using GitHub's editor, Atom, I would like to know if it's possible to have autocompletion for the project, in other words a plugin or option that would look in all the file's project and complete the words according to the project, a bit like the plugin YouCompleteMe in Vim.

Answer (score 4):

It is built in as <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> (search for *autocomplete* in the command search)  or you can install [autocomplete-plus (link)](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus) which delivers them without the hotkey requirement.